# Keep aspect ratio with image width in css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to fix the aspect ratio of images given a smaller width using css? Maybe by using jQuery / javascript?

Thanks!

Comment: Curious how well this question (and accepted answer) apply to HTML canvas.  Everything was going swimmingly (they act like images so I can just style one dimension) until I noticed IE9 does not follow this rule and distorts aspect ratio

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With plain CSS, you could set only one dimension of the images, either `width` or `height` and set the other as `auto`, e.g.:

```
.thumb { 
  width:200px;
  height:auto;
}
```

The images will have a fixed 200px width, and the height will depend on the aspect ratio.

Comment: nice one. didn't know this :)

Comment: This will stop shrunken images from pixelating?

Comment: @lnostdal, what doesn't work? What have you tried? Post an example of what's not working, I'm pretty sure it [does work](http://jsbin.com/ujageh)...

Comment: Does not work for me. Tested with IE, FF, Chrome ! Image is always scaled to fill full parent.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the jQuery solution ;)

```
function fixImage(elm) {
            elm = $(elm);
            var x = elm[0];

            var allowedHeight = 80;
            var allowedWidth = 80;
            if (width > height) {
                elm.css('width', allowedWidth + 'px');
                elm.css('height', 'auto');
            }
            else {

                elm.css('height', allowedHeight + 'px');
                elm.css('width', 'auto');

            }
}
```

Comment: Welcome on SO! I edited your question to reflect the fact this is a jQuery solution. What does x do? What'll allowed* do in each case (I guess what it does but comments from author would be better). Why 80? Any example of use? (dummyimage.com won't work anymore but placekitten.com is a good replacement)